# Rails: Loading Highstock using while loop not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, series

I'm trying to use a while loop to populate my highstock series.
As I might have multiple graphs which is dependent on the data in the database I need to use a while loop.

Below is my code for the highchart series:

```
          series: [
              <% num_active_deals = @active_deals_daily_count.size %>
              <% num = 0 %>
              <% visibility = true %>
              <% while num < num_active_deals %>
                  {
                      name: <%= @active_deals_daily_count[num][0] + ' view count' %>,
                      pointStart: <%= @active_deals_daily_count[num][1] %>,
                      pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                      data: <%= @active_deals_daily_count[num][3] %>,
                      visible: <%= visibility %>
                  }, {
                      name: <%= @active_deals_daily_count[num][0] + ' redemption count' %>,
                      pointStart: <%= @active_deals_daily_count[num][2] %>,
                      pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                      data: <%= @active_deals_daily_count[num][4] %>,
                      visible: <%= visibility %>
                  }
                  <% num = num + 1 %>
                  <% if num != num_active_deals %>
                    ,
                  <% end %>

                  <% visibility = false %>
              <% end %>
          ]
```

My @active_deals_daily_count contains the following data:

```
[["Citibank", 1443628800000, 1443628800000, [0], [0]],["DBS", 1443628800000, 1443628800000, [0], [0]],["UOB", 1443628800000, 1443628800000, [0], [0]], ["POSB", 1443628800000, 1443628800000, [0], [0]], ["Great Eastern", 1443628800000, 1443628800000, [3,6,10,13,16,20,23,23], [3,5,6,7,8,9,12,16]]]
```

I understand that for the first 4, there won't be any data loaded but I expected at least the name of the graph will appear as well as the last one.

At the current stage, I am just left with a blank space where the chart is supposed to be.

I have looked through many guides and still could not figure out where i went wrong. Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Instead of using while and a bunch of erb interpolation you should select the records from the database and use map to transform the data into a ruby object with the correct structure. Then use JSON::encode to convert to a format for highcharts to consume.

Comment: To give a more concrete example i would need to know what the input data looks like.

Comment: Hi @max I'm not sure if this is what you mean. For example since i am looping through active_deals_daily_count which contents are as follow above, if num = 4 it will return me the following.

active_deals_daily_count[4][0] = "Great Eastern"

active_deals_daily_count[4][1] = "1443628800000"

active_deals_daily_count[4][2] = "1443628800000"

active_deals_daily_count[4][3] = [3,6,10,13,16,20,23,23]

active_deals_daily_count[4][4] = [3,5,6 7, 8,9,12,16]

Answer (score 1):

I realised the error.

It is in fact not my code error but javascript error instead.

For

```
name: <%= @active_deals_daily_count[num][0] + ' view count' %>,
```

javascript does not detect the " " that states it as a string therefore, it throws an error and it never loads.

By changing to

```
name: "<%= @active_deals_daily_count[num][0] %> " + ' view count' %>
```

it works perfectly

Hope it helps anyone else facing the same problem!